# Determine if the expression is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm tryin to solve this:

Determine $k$ such that $\frac{k^2-87}{3k+117}$ is an integer.

I think chinese remainder theorem will be useful, but i don't see how.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly, $3$ needs to divide  $k\implies k=3a$(say)

$$\implies \frac{k^2-87}{3k+117}=\frac{(3a)^2-87}{3(3a)+117}=\frac{3a^2-29}{3(a+13)}=a-13+\frac{478}{3(a+13)}$$

Observe that $478$ is not divisible by $3$ unlike the denominator

So, there is no solution is integers

Comment: Why did you divide the denominator by 9 and the numerator by 3?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Rectified.

Answer (score 3):

Since $3k+117=3(k+39)$, $k^2-87$ must be a multiple of $3$. $87=3\cdot29$, so $k^2$ must be a multiple of $3$, which means that $k=3\ell$ for some integer $\ell$. Then

$$\frac{k^2-87}{3k+117}=\frac{9\ell^2-3\cdot29}{3(3\ell+39)}=\frac{3\ell^2-29}{3\ell+39}=\frac{3\ell^2-29}{3(\ell+13)}\;;$$

can that ever be an integer?

Comment: you wrote "...be a multiple of $\,3.87=3\cdot 29$..." . That gramatical period between $\;3\;$ and $\;87\;$ is confusing: it looks as a multiplication dot and for a while it misled me. Beginning sentencese with some mathematical expressions doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If integer $d$ divides $k^2-87$ and $3k+117,$

$d$ must divide $k(3k+117)-3(k^2-87)=9(13k+29)$

So, $9$ must divide $k^2-87\iff k^2\equiv87\pmod 9\equiv6$

But, $(\pm1)^2\equiv1, (\pm2)^2\equiv4, (\pm3)^2\equiv 0, (\pm4)^2\equiv7\pmod 9 \implies k^2\not\equiv6\pmod 9$

Answer (score 1):

By using MAPLE, we can probe the case machinery. Just give the software the following code:

```
 for k from 0 to 2^20 do msolve(k^2-87 = 0, 3*k+117) od;
```

You will get nothing. Note  that  it takes time to see the result since $2^{20}$ may be a considerable number for our computers.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yep, I tried that. Should I go into synaptic and do a complete removal?

Comment: I got the same thing.